# Doctrine2: get count of one to many relation directly mapped in entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I'm using doctrine2 and symfony3.1

I have a list of `Movie` for which people can buy `Ticket`, using a one to many relationship

On the dashboard I would like to display the list of movies, with the number of tickets bought for each

I get the data I want by doing this

```
    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $builder = $manager->createQueryBuilder();

    $results = $builder
        ->select('m')
        ->from('AppBundle:Movie', 'm')
        ->addSelect($builder->expr()->count('t'))
        ->leftJoin('m.tickets', 't')
        ->groupBy('m.id')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
```

it produces for 100 movies,  1 requests:

```
SELECT
       e0_.title AS title_0,
       e0_.is_published AS is_published_1,
       e0_.description AS description_2,
       e0_.author AS author_3,
       e0_.director AS director_4,
       e0_.artist_list AS artist_list_5,
       e0_.tags_list AS tags_list_6,
       e0_.creation_time AS creation_time_7,
       e0_.id AS id_8,
       COUNT(t1_.id) AS sclr_9,
       e0_.place_id AS place_id_10,
       e0_.organization_id AS organization_id_11,
       e0_.inner_image1_id AS inner_image1_id_12,
       e0_.inner_image2_id AS inner_image2_id_13,
       e0_.inner_image3_id AS inner_image3_id_14,
       e0_.image_id AS image_id_15
FROM event e0_
LEFT JOIN event_occurence e2_ ON e0_.id = e2_.event_id
LEFT JOIN ticket t1_ ON e2_.id = t1_.occurence_id
WHERE e0_.organization_id = '956744cb-6f76-4328-8ea5-c9715d762509'
GROUP BY e0_.id
LIMIT 100;
```

which is perfectly what I want in term of SQL request emitted.

The problem is on the ORM side, that the results is organized like this

```
[
   [ movie, nbrTickets],
   [ movie, nbrTickets],
   [ movie, nbrTickets],
]
```

I would like to know how to give hints to Doctrine so that `nbrTickets` become a property of `Movie` directly, (currently I have to iterate myself) while still doing only **1 SQL query** (I strongly emphasi so I don't want to do `movie.tickets | length` in my twig

The answer should meet the following requirements:

- doing **1 and only one** SQL query ( => otherwise as my page display 100 movies, it will issue, only for this, 101 queries)
- permit to directly access the result from within the entity ( => otherwise as said above, I already have a solution that retrieve the data I want, I'm interested on making the code to stick more to the ORM)
- not retrieve too much data.

The answer "it's currently not possible with doctrine" is also acceptable.

Comment: What's wrong with using `{{ movie.tickets | length }}` in your Twig file? That seems like an easy solution. Or maybe you need the count in the Controller?

Comment: because doing so triggers n+1 problem the https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/n_plus_one/  , now doing so will require doing N more SQL requests to display N movies

Comment: I see only one solution here. Hydrate result to an array. Than you can pass whatever you want. So `getArrayResult()` should work here instead of `getResult()` but of course you don't get an object.

Comment: Or another thing. If you do something like `->select('m','result')->leftJoin('m.results', 'result')` you can use `{{ movie.tickets|length}}`and it should make one db query.

Comment: @user254319 hmm interesting but wouldn't that mean the ORM will create in PHP memory the 13456 Tickets objects if a movie as sold that many ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it seems there's no simple way to get it mapped directly in the entity. You can only do approximative solution: (which get the job done but not as elegantly)

- using `$movie->tickets->count()` which is elegant but too costly (you do 1 more sql request for each movie)
- using a `addSelect` (my current solution) which does 1 request to get all the data, but which need additional code to map the count in your entity.

It seems there was a solution in Doctrine 1 as explained [here](https://www.theodo.fr/blog/2011/07/get-objects-and-related-count-in-one-shot/) as you were able to access a special attribute `$this->_values` containing the non-mapped value from within the entity which seems to no more be the case.

Answer (score 1):

You need proper annotations for the relation to work in Movie and Ticket entity.

Movie entity:

```
 * One user has Many tickets.
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Ticket", mappedBy="user")
 */
private $tickets;
```

Ticket entity:

```
 * Many tickets have One movie.
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="movie", inversedBy="tickets")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="movie_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $movie;
```

For the relation you need to define an array collection in the constructor

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->tickets = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

You need to create a getTickets function for the Movie entity like that:

```
 * tickets
 *
 * @return arrayCollection
 */
public function getTickets()
{
    return $this->tickets;
}
```

Then you retrieve the movies with the following repository call:

```
    $movies = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:movies')
        ->findAll();
```

and finally you retrieve the tickets:

```
    $tickets = $movies[0]->getTickets()
```

and you count them with:

```
    $tickets->count()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's already what i have (i should have precised it). This will issue one count request pert movie , so if I display the top 100 of best selling movies, now my page issue 101 query.

Comment: I have updated my question so that it's clearer what I'm looking for.